# {{=XML(some thing)}} can't be parsed in html with web2py

Tags: html, json, character-encoding, web2py, magicsuggest

I am using magicsuggest as a auto-complete plugin of a web application with web2py. I define a list variable `dt=['张','李']` in the model/db.py. The element in the list is Chinese. However when I embeded the variable in the html like`{{=XML(dt)}}` according to the manual book of magicsuggest. The chinese character was garbled. After several days searching, I find the list variable with chinese character was encode into hex in the html. I know there is something wrong about encode/decode. Could someone help me to display the correct chinese character in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XML()` is meant to take a string, not a list of strings. If you pass it something other than a string, it will first be converted to a string, so your code is equivalent to `{{=XML(str(dt))}}`, and you'll notice that in Python, `str(['张','李'])` yields `"['\\xe5\\xbc\\xa0', '\\xe6\\x9d\\x8e']"`.

Instead, you can do `{{=XML(dt[0])}}`, and you will see the first character in the list displayed properly.

If you want to display a comma separated list surrounded by brackets, you can do:

```
{{=json.dumps(dt, encoding="UTF-8", ensure_ascii=False)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. {{=XML(dt[0])}} can be displayed properly in the html side. However, what I want to send to the html side is a list of strings. Luckily I find a solution. I add the following code after I define the dt=['张','李'], import json
dt=json.dumps(dt, encoding="UTF-8", ensure_ascii=False). Then {{=XML(dt)}} in the html can be parsed into a list of string. Any other mehtod?

Comment: It wasn't clear you wanted to display exactly `["张","李"]`, but if that's the goal, your solution seems fine. I have updated the answer accordingly.